# Android WebView setInitialScale() that the content does not needs to be scrolled horizonally

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to display a webpage, which can be horizontally scrolled, because it is to big. When I set `useWideViewPort()` it is not anymore too big, but there is much unused space and the content is viewed very small. So i decided to scale it only a bit down by doing this:

```
var first = true

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                if (first) {
                    first = false

                    class CustomJavascriptInterface {

                        private var mContext: Context? = null

                        fun JavaScriptInterface(c: Context?) {
                            mContext = c
                        }

                        @JavascriptInterface
                        fun catchOuterWidth(x: Int, y: Int) {
                            view?.setInitialScale(x / y)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    view?.addJavascriptInterface(CustomJavascriptInterface(), "CustomJavascriptInterface")
                    view?.loadUrl("javascript:CustomJavascriptInterface.catchOuterWidth(window.outerWidth, document.body.scrollWidth); void 0")
                }
            }
```

but I can't get it to work. Or is there any other way to do what i want?

Answer (score 0):

view?.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true)